# Are there any trigonometric identities involving either $\sin ^{-1}(2 x)$ or $\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Are there any (nontrivial) trigonometric (half-angle/double-angle) identities involving either $\sin ^{-1}(2 x)$ or $\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$?

I have a series of expressions of the form ($n=2$)
\begin{equation}
\pi  \sqrt{-4 x^2-y^2+4}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-8 \sqrt{-x^2-y^2+1} \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{2
   \sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
+2 \sqrt{-4 x^2-y^2+4} \sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)
\end{equation}
and ($n=3$)
\begin{equation}
\pi  \sqrt{-x^2-y^2+1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-2 \sqrt{-x^2-y^2+1} \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{3
   y}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
+6 \sqrt{-x^2-9 y^2+1} \sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\ldots
\end{equation}
which I'm interested in manipulating for integration purposes.
For example, I want to integrate the $n=2$ expression over $-1<x<1\land \sqrt{1-x^2}+y>0\land y<0$, and the $n=3$ expression over $-1<x<1\land y>0\land \sqrt{1-x^2}-3 y>0$. (Perhaps some changes-of-variables would be useful.)

Comment: $\arcsin(2x)$ might not even be defined (if $|x|>\frac{1}{2}$).  Could you put your question in context?